# synchronize the local database with deployed project in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

When I logged in the project deployed on Heroku with a registered account, [Learning Log](https://hero-learning-log.herokuapp.com/), it starts freshly without any data I have entered in the local project.

I'm aware that Heroku employed Postgres while my local database is python's contributed sqlite.

Additionally, I ignored the `*.sqlite3` in git repository following the tutorial.(When undo the ignore, it not works)

I prefer to work locally, push local data to remote and fetch remote to local.

How could I synchronize remote with local?

Comment: you mean your deploying database is postgres in server?

Comment: Yes, `dj_database_url.config(default="postgres://localhost"),` @seuling

Comment: then why don't you connect that database while you using local runserver?

Comment: Could you please post the comment to answer. @seuling

Comment: oh sorry for late. I will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your database for your server in local runserver.

Just change your database setting for your server ip. (first you have to open 5432 port in your for your local ip)

like below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'your_server_db_name',
        'USER': 'your_server_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_server_db_pw',
        'HOST': 'your_server_ip',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Then the db is synchronized. However, I don't recommend this way. Whenever you migrate / or do sth concerned with db, it must be crashed because you can't modify code both.

So if you want more active database from real db, you just use `pg_dump` for dumping sql and add it to your local database.

Comment: You comment "Then the db is synchronized" isn't true. You're using the same database then, the production database. And then you correctly point out that this is not recommended, but basically you're not giving an answer to the question.

Comment: @moojen You're right. "Synchronized" is the wrong word. I just want to say that if use a production database in a local server, it doesn't necessary to take care of synchronization between local/production databases.